# Is there a specific name for a function with the symmetry $f(x,y)=f(-x,-y)$?

Tags: calculus

A single valued function $f(x)$ is said to be symmetric if $f(x)=f(-x)$.

But what do you call a multivariate function with the property $f(x,y)=f(-x,-y)$?

I haven't found a definite answer online, but I have 3 possible proposals

1. Reflection symmetric
2. Mirror symmetric
3. Time symmetric

Which one, if any, would you say is the correct one?

Comment: Perhaps “even”? We typically say a function $f$ is even if $f(x)=f(-x)$ for all $x$.

Comment: @csch2 I think that you are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called *even symmetric*. See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even_and_odd_functions#Multivariate_functions).

Answer (score 2):

[According to Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EvenFunction.html), such a function is actually called *even*, and so is a function $f(x_1, x_2, ..., x_n)$ of $n$ variables satisfying $f(x_1, x_2, ..., x_n) = f(-x_1, -x_2, ..., -x_n)$. Similarly, the multivariable function $f$ is said to be odd if $-f(x_1, x_2, ..., x_n) = f(-x_1, -x_2, ..., -x_n)$, again [according to Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/OddFunction.html), just as in the one-variable case.